# Protect a Magento store from blocking

Tags: magento2

I am looking for an alternative to `Shopify`. My store after developing was blocked with probably no reason (typical situation with Shopify). So I am really afraid what's goes wrong at the most important moments. That`s why I am looking for an alternative to Shopify. And I think Magento is something I am looking for.

So I have a  question:

1) Can I protect myself and my store from blocking ? I mean can I provide To Magento Team all necessary information (like ID, business info/details and so on...) to get verified and approved before launching to avoid any troubles like blocking my store in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Just host the software on your own server. This way, you can't be blocked instead of by your hoster. Choose a well-known hoster in your market, and you shouldn't get any problems as long as you pay the bills.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't block or have control to block your website if you use the community version of Magento which is completely open-source. 
You can download Magento, make website and host and point the domain after development. Take care of domain and hosting renewal only that's it.